# How can I remove all borders from a group of elements except for the one created?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically make all borders disappear except the newest created container's border I have tried the commented out section of the JavaScript.  Can someone please provide an explanation/example of how this can be done?

```js
function countButtonLinks() {
    var elementGroups = document.getElementById('containsAll');

    if(elementGroups.children.length == 0) {
        var numID = 1;
    }

    if(elementGroups.children.length == 1) {
        var numID = 2;
    }

    if(elementGroups.children.length == 2) {
        var numID = 3;
    }

    if(elementGroups.children.length == 3) {
        var numID = 4;
    }

    if(elementGroups.children.length == 4) {
        var numID = 5;
    }

    if(elementGroups.children.length == 5) {
        var numID = 6;
    }

    return numID;
}

function createContainer() {
    if(document.getElementById('containsAll').children.length < 6) {
        var elementA = document.createElement("span");
        var elementAInnerTxt = document.createElement("div");

        elementA.id = 'elem' + countButtonLinks();
        elementAInnerTxt.id = 'elemInner' + countButtonLinks();
        elementA.className = 'elem1';
        elementAInnerTxt.className = 'elemInner1';
        elementA.appendChild(elementAInnerTxt);

        document.getElementById('containsAll').appendChild(elementA);
    }
}
```

```css
.containsAll {
    width: 91%;
    height: 75%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 91;
    border: 1px #000000 solid;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.elem1 {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 60px;
    float: left;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px #333333 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.elemInner1 {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 60px;
    float: left;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 5px;
}

.buttonClass {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonClass" type="button" onclick="createContainer();">Click Me</button>
<div id="containsAll" class="containsAll"></div>
```

Please, no JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function countButtonLinks(){
    var elementGroups = document.getElementById('containsAll');
    // you don't need to use 'var numID'
    return elementGroups.children.length + 1; 
}

function createContainer(){
if(document.getElementById('containsAll').children.length < 6){

  // add code here
  for(var i=0;i<document.getElementById('containsAll').children.length;i++){
    document.getElementById('containsAll').children[i].style.border = '0 none';
  }

var elementA = document.createElement("span");

//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the existing children of the element and remove the border before inserting
another element:

```
function countButtonLinks(){
    var elementGroups = document.getElementById('containsAll');
    var groupLength = elementGroups.children.length;

    return groupLength++;
}

function createContainer() {
    var containsAll = document.getElementById('containsAll'),
        childrenLength = containsAll.children.length;

    if (childrenLength >= 6) {
        return; // Bail immediately since we only need to add a new element if the children's length is less than 6
    }

    // Call previous children
    for ( var i = 0; i < childrenLength; i++ ) {
        let child = containsAll.children[i];

        // You can add a new class here that will remove the border
        // but in this example, we'll use the style attribute to remove the border
        child.style.border = 0;
    }

    // Now, add the new element
    var elementA = document.createElement("span");
    var elementAInnerTxt = document.createElement("div");
    elementA.id = 'elem' + countButtonLinks();
    elementAInnerTxt.id = 'elemInner' + countButtonLinks();
    elementA.className = 'elem1';
    elementAInnerTxt.className = 'elemInner1';
    elementA.appendChild(elementAInnerTxt);
    containsAll.appendChild(elementA);
}
```

Also, if you're going to use an element multiple times inside a function, make it a habit to store that element in a variable so you don't repeatedly calls the `document.getElementById` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the CSS [:last-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');

function count_button_links()
{
    return container.children.length + 1;
}

function new_container()
{
    if (count_button_links() > 6) return false;
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.id = 'el_' + count_button_links();
    span.className = 'box';
    container.appendChild(span);
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 5px;
    display:flex;
    height:200px;
}
.box {
    flex:0 0 100px;
    height:60px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.box:last-child{
    border:1px solid #333;
}
button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="new_container();">Click Me</button>

<div id="container"></div>
```